# How to modify header? retrofit2, sharedpreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit

I'm making service that makes user able to login in LoginActivity, and if login is successful, user can post something in PostActivity. I'm using Restful api.

I found good sharedpreference example on github : https://gist.github.com/nikhiljha/52d45ca69a8415c6990d2a63f61184ff
and 
https://gist.github.com/tsuharesu/cbfd8f02d46498b01f1b

**AddCookiesInterceptor.java**

```
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    public static final String PREF_COOKIES = "PREF_COOKIES";

    private Context context;

    public AddCookiesInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();

        HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet<String>) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getStringSet(PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<String>());

        for (String cookie : preferences) {
          builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
        }

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}
```

**RecievedCookiesInterceptor.java**

```
public class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private Context context;
    public ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    } 
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
            HashSet<String> cookies = (HashSet<String>) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", new HashSet<String>());
            for (String header : originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
                cookies.add(header);
            }
            SharedPreferences.Editor memes = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
            memes.putStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", cookies).apply();
            memes.commit();
        }
        return originalResponse;
    }
}
```

I used this code very well on my LoginActivity like this,

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.interceptors().add(new AddCookiesInterceptor(getApplicationContext()));
builder.interceptors().add(new RecievedCookiesInterceptor(getApplicationContext()));
client = builder.build();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(LoginApiService.Login_API_URL)
        .build();

loginApiService = retrofit.create(LoginApiService.class);

Call<ResponseBody> getkey = loginApiService.getkey(loginData);
getkey.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if(response.code() == 200) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PostActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

But in PostActivity, (it's from `if (response.code() == 200)` `startActivity`)

I used this like

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.interceptors().add(new AddCookiesInterceptor(getApplicationContext()));
#just used AddCookiesInterceptor, Not RecievedCookiesInterceptor

    client = builder.build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(PostApiService.Post_API_URL)
            .build();
    PostApiService = retrofit.create(PostApiService.class);
```

It give me HTTP/1.1 401 error, I found it means there is problem in Headers.

I write PostApiService like this

```
public interface PostApiService {
    @POST("posts/")
    Call<ResponseBody> gettest(@Body TextData textData);}
```

**My question :**

I want Header like 
`key : Authorization` // 
`value : Token e0af91707f0434a1a2a7581dd3f4f483bdd717`

Where do i modify?

I know too much codes bothers you maybe, so I have to say i'm very sorry.

Comment: How about making an interceptor that adds that header and adding it to the client? Should look similar to your `AddCookiesInterceptor`.

Comment: @nasch , Thanks for your advice, but i use restapi that retrurned json response, and that json response is came on body, not headers. So i have trouble with doing it, cause of my poor knowledge. please help me with giving some hint?

Comment: Is your problem with adding headers to the request or handling the response?

Comment: No, my problem is catch response from rest api. i.e. i POST request to api like json  {"id":"any_value11", "password":"any_value22"} and gain json response like {"key":"any_value33"}. i want use or catch `any_value33` of {"key":"any_value33"}. On my postman, {"key":"any_value33"} is on body. not headers. Could you help me? /// Actually after I asked this Question on stackoverflow yesterday, while i tried to solve this, my important question was changed from above question.

Comment: Sounds like you should edit your question to reflect your current issue or ask a new one. Feel free to post a link to a new one.